# How to pass the javascript variable value from one html page to the another html page?

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, ajax

I am creating the quiz application using JavaScript and Django. Actually entire logic was done in the JavaScript . For the quiz application ,I have a score variable that score variable value i am showing in the index.html as show below:

```
          resultCont.innerHTML = 'Your Score:- ' + score + '/80' ;
```

Here score is the JavaScript variable.

Another thing I need to store this score variable into my DB . So that I need to use the ajax to post the score variable to my views.py file where my function is running to submit the score along with username to the Django models.

**models.py:**

```
class Results(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50,default='')
    score = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

Here I have taken the username and score variable . And the username is the foreign key.

**views.py**

```
def score(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render(request, 'quiz/html/end.html',{'form':Score()})
    else:
        try:
            form = Score(data=request.POST)
            newscore = form.save(commit=False)
            newscore.owner = request.user
            newscore.save()
            return redirect('category')
        except ValueError:
            return render(request, 'quiz/html/end.html',{'form':Score(), 'error' :'please fill the form properly'})
```

**end.html:** Here I have used the form to submit the score along with name . I hidden the username so that user cannot change the name.

```
<form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}

        <div>
            <p style="display:none;">
                <label for="id_username">Username:</label>
                <input type="text" name="username" value={{user.username}} placeholder="{{user.username}}" maxlength="50" required="" id="id_username">
            </p>

            <p>
                <label for="id_score">Score:</label>
                <input type="number" name="score" placeholder ='' value='I want the score value here from javascsript' required="" id="id_score">         
            </p>
        </div>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>

    </form>
```

I wrote the ajax post request but i tried  of showing score in the same index.html. It is displaying but i want that score value in the end.html. Is it possible to show the score of index.html(score storing in the #result) into the end.html (where the score need to store )

```
function scoresubmit(){
          $.ajax({
            url: '/',
            method : 'POST',
            // data: {score: $('#score').val(), "csrfmiddlewaretoken" : "{{csrf_token}}"},
            success: function() {
              $('#name').html(score);
            }
             });
            }
```

**index.html:   (from here)**

```
resultCont.innerHTML = 'Your Score:- ' + score + '/80' ;
```

**end.html:(to Here)**

```
 <input type="number" name="score" placeholder ='' value='I want the score value here from javascsript' required="" id="id_score">
```

**urls.py:**

```
path('home', views.home,name = "home"),
    path('main',views.main, name='main'),
    path('', views.score, name = "score"),
    path('profile/',views.profile, name = "profile"),
    path('category/',views.category, name = "category"),
```

**Only thing I want here is store the score along with the user name  in my DB (Django).**

What is the wrong in my ajax code . How to pass the value from one to another html using ajax post request?

Comment: Is the Score() that you are using in your views another model?

Comment: @ms394 No class Score(ModelForm):
    class Meta():
        model = Results
        fields = ['username','quizname','score']


    I just used the forms.py file here

Comment: @ms394 Can you tell me how to pass the Javascript value to the djangi models.

Comment: @ms394 is the correct process to store the data . Once if you know please just say the way : -( dude I want that process badly right now so . Just the way or any links

Comment: Have u verified in the Admin if the data is saving in db?

Comment: Yes when the form is submitting manually it is storing but the score should not give manually right so i stuck there and i stopped the process.@ms394

Answer (score 1):

Hey below is the code i tried. 
I created a form in index.html. Took dummy input, marks and performed some operation on it and sent variable score to the end.html and also stored it in the db. 
Since i was working with JS ajax, i used djano-rest framwork for the same.
Below is the code

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


# Create your models here.
class Results(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    score = models.IntegerField()
    marks = models.IntegerField()
```

index.html

```
body>
    <form id="scoreform" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <p class="marks">
            <label for="marks">Marks</label>
            <input type="number" name='marks' id="id_marks">
        </p>

        <input type="submit"  id="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</body>

<script src="{% static 'main.js' %}"></script>
```

end.html

```
<body>
    <form id="scoreform" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <p class="username">
            <label for="username">Label</label>
            <input type="text" name="username" value={{score.user}}>
        </p>
        <p class="scores">
            <label for="score">Score</label>
            <input type="number" name='score' id="score-value" value={{score.score}}>
        </p>

    </form>
</body>
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import Results
from .forms import Score
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response
from .serializers import ResultSerializer

# Create your views here.
@api_view(['GET','POST'])
@login_required(login_url='users:login')
def score(request):
    form = Score()
    print(1)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = ResultSerializer(data=request.data)
        print(serializer)
        if (serializer.is_valid()):
            print(3)
            serializer.save(user = request.user)
            return Response(request.user.pk)
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'form': form})
    #return redirect('score:end', pk=request.user.pk)   

@login_required(login_url='users:login')
def end(request, pk):
    score = Results.objects.get(pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'end.html', {'score':score})
```

This also has login feature, as i wanted to tag a user to the score. 
I dunno who clear this would be for you. But i seriously hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this
In the views.py file if the method is GET, then create an instance of the Result Model like result = Result.objects.get(pk = pk) the pk refers to primary key to get 
the result of a particular user, and pass in some unique identified to your views method like pk. 
Then use template tag to display in the end.html

Comment: I have a score value in the javascript and now i want that value to store in the DB along with username how to get  that. once please explain . provide me the sample code @ms394

Comment: I just trying from the one week it jis not even storing please help me @ms394 I need to submit the project if it is storing in the DB : -(